Do rational inequalities preserve componentwise convex combinations?
I'm working with conjunctive formulas without negations in $\langle\mathbb{Q},<, =, \rangle$. My question is whether if I have two relations $R(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ and $R(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ that may use constants, it is necessarily the case that for all $\epsilon \in [0,1]$, $R(\epsilon a_1 + (1-\epsilon) b_1,\ldots,\epsilon a_n + (1-\epsilon) b_n)$.

When you say "I have two relations $R(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and $R(b_1,\dots,b_n)$", presumably you mean that $R(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is a formula in your restricted class (a conjunction of atomic formulas with parameters from $\mathbb{Q}$ in the language of order) such that $\mathbb{Q}\models R(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and $\mathbb{Q}\models R(b_1,\dots,b_n)$.
Assuming that's what you mean, the answer to your question is yes. Let's say a formula is convex if it satisfies your condition. Then every conjunction of atomic formulas with parameters from $\mathbb{Q}$ in the language of order is convex.
Fix a variable context $x_1,\dots,x_n$. I claim that every atomic formula is convex. The subsets of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ defined by atomic formulas are:

$\varnothing$
$\mathbb{Q}^n$
A hyperplane defined by $x_i = c$ for some $i$ and some $c\in \mathbb{Q}$.
A diagonal defined by $x_i = x_j$ for some $i\neq j$
An orthogonal half-space defined by $x_i < c$ or $c < x_i$ for some $i$ and some $c\in \mathbb{Q}$
A diagonal half-space defined by $x_i < x_j$ for some $i\neq j$.

It's easy to check that all of these sets are convex, and hence the formulas defining them are convex. For example, to verify that the diagonal half-space defined by $x_i<x_j$ is convex, suppose $\overline{a},\overline{b}\in \mathbb{Q}^n$ lie in this half-space, so  $a_i<a_j$ and $b_i<b_j$. Then for any $\epsilon\in [0,1]$, $\epsilon a_i + (1-\epsilon)b_i < \epsilon a_j + (1-\epsilon)b_j$, so $\epsilon \overline{a}+(1-\epsilon)\overline{b}$ also lies in the half-space.
Now I claim that if $\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_k$ are convex formulas in variable context $x_1,\dots,x_n$, then $\psi = \bigwedge_{i=1}^k \varphi_i$ is convex. This comes down to the fact that an intersection of convex sets is convex. Here's the proof.
Suppose $\mathbb{Q}\models \psi(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and $\mathbb{Q}\models \psi(b_1,\dots,b_n)$. Let $\epsilon\in [0,1]$. For all $1\leq i \leq k$, we have $\mathbb{Q}\models \varphi_i(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and $\mathbb{Q}\models \varphi_i(b_1,\dots,b_n)$, so $\mathbb{Q}\models \varphi_i(\epsilon a_1+(1-\epsilon)b_1,\dots,\epsilon a_n + (1-\epsilon)b_n)$, since $\varphi_i$ is convex. Since $i$ was arbitrary, $\mathbb{Q}\models \psi(\epsilon a_1+(1-\epsilon)b_1,\dots,\epsilon a_n + (1-\epsilon)b_n)$
